# How to bootstrap a cell to row-span=2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make via the boostrap way the red cell be `row-span=2` (fill also the second row)?

```css
.cell {height: 100px; border: 1px solid; border-collapse:collapse;}
.red {background: red;}
.yel {background: lightyellow;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-3 cell yel">content 1 -3</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 2 -5</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 cell red">content 3 -4</div>
<div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 4 -5</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 cell yel">content 5 -3</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Simplest way would probably be something like `style="height:200px !important;` on `<div>` for "content 3 -4", since you're using fixed height for cells. Correct way? Probably not.

Comment: that height will also move down the 45 and 53 cells ... not good

Comment: You're really asking for equal-height columns here. (The fact that the first column has two nested rows is irrelevant.) Give that a search for some good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 2) Imitation using `.pull-right` & red row

```css
.cell { min-height: 100px !important; outline: 1px solid; }
.red { background: red; }
.yel { background: lightyellow; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
      
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row red">
    <div class="col-xs-3 cell yel">content 1 -3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 2 -5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">content 3 -4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 4 -5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 cell yel">content 5 -3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### 1) Imitation using `.pull-right` & `height: 200px;`

1. You can use [the `.pull-right` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats) to make this cell right-floating.
2. And increase the height of the cell.

```css
.cell        { height: 100px; outline: 1px solid; }
.double-cell { height: 200px; outline: 1px solid; }
.red { background: red; }
.yel { background: lightyellow; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
      
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 cell yel">content 1 -3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 2 -5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 double-cell red pull-right">content 3 -4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 4 -5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 cell yel">content 5 -3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @isherwood Thank you for your critique. I agree.I've added one more solution, but it's still just an imitation of the real `row-span`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

Check working example at **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/Egjmvz?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 1 -5</div>
      <div class="col-xs-7 cell yel">content 2 -7</div>
      <div class="col-xs-7 cell yel">content 4 -7</div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 cell yel">content 5 -5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 red">content 3 -4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cell {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.yel {
  background: lightyellow;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Enjoy :)

Comment: Note that this relies on flexbox, which has some browser support concerns (IE). http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @isherwood  Although it works perfect for IE 10 and above. There are workaround available in css and js both to tackle the issue old browsers[IE8 and IE9].

Comment: thanks for your solution... the little problem is that I generate the div-cells, and I should respect the order, keeping them one after another. in your case the order is broken, and I have a separate cell... I need to be able to apply the solution to an abstract list of cells...